# How to use OR in pdo Query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I don't know why it's now working. I am trying my best to solve this problem but don't know how to do this. Is this correct query for PDO?
Thanks
Araf.

```
$userNo = $this->test_input($data['userNo']);
$nid = $this->test_input(implode("", $data['nid']));

$query = "SELECT id FROM test_users WHERE user_no = :usr_no OR nid = :nid";

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([
      ':usr_no' => $userNo,
      ':nid' => $nid
]);
```

Comment: If there is an error, you need to ask PDO for it. Cf. https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php or https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: It's just showing me 0000 I didn't get it. @Dormilich

Comment: @ArafHossain  Why do you try to attach `db_name` ? PDO makes a connection to DB when it's instantiated. Just try 

`$query = "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE user_no = :usr_no OR nid = :nid";`

Comment: I have tried bro doesn't work @vivek_23

Comment: @ArafHossain I don't see a reason as to why it shouldn't. Is the name of your database table `table_name` ?

Comment: everything is okay. I figured it out. Giving answer in here. Just a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added this line after this Nid.

and changed the name of (variable) to $nidInput.

just like below.

```
$nidInput = $this->test_input(implode("", $data['nid']));
$nid = empty($nidInput) ? null : $nidInput;
```

Now, it's working fine.